# How can I modify my icomoon icon color without using :before?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, icomoon

I'm using custom icomoon icons and bootstrap for my project. I'm putting my icons inside .btn .btn-primary divs. While the text changes naturally, the icon remains the same. What can I do to make it work? I'm sincerely stuck here. Thanks in advance.

here's example code:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary"><i class="icon-loop"></i>text here</button>
```

I want my  to be affected by the button css.

edit: I found the solution. Do not include any color specifications in your css and it'll work

Comment: Please show us you basic code, especially the styling but related HTML as well and if possible make a working snippet (ie include any relevant libraries) see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @AHaworth could you help out now?